# How to wait for the middleware to finish before loading the page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am on Vue2 and Nuxt. I want ended my requests in middleware before load page. How create that ?
How can I wait for the end of my request before loading my page?

```
export default ({ store }) => {
  fetchTest(store, Authorization);
};

async function fetchTest(store, Authorization) {
  return await axios
    .get("/test", {
        headers: {
            Authorization,
        },
    })
    .then(res => {
        // somethings...
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
  });
};
```

Comment: If you `async/await`, it should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either in the **route middleware** or directly in the router hook **beforeEach**

Like here:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
   if (needToFetch) {
      await fetchTest()
   }

   next()
})
```

Look here [Route Guard -> Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Or you can run your code in a hook **created** by the main component and handle the rendering of your content with the specified flag

Example:

```
<template>
   <div v-if="loading">loader</div>
   <div v-else>content</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                loading: true
            }
        },
        async created() {
            await fetchData()
            
            this.loading = false
        }
    }
</script>
```